# Trying to Consolidate using Excel - Need to Concatenate

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a mail list that I need to merge the duplicate addresses together and concatenate the names. Example below:

```
Name        Street_Address
---------   ----------------
JohnDoe     444 Elm Street
JaneDoe     444 Elm Street
BillyBob    456 Birch Street
BugsBunny   999 Maple Street
BabsBunny   999 Maple Street
```

I would like to merge the duplicates like so:

```
Name                 Street_Address
------------------   ----------------
JohnDoeJaneDoe       444 Elm Street
BillyBob             456 Birch Street
BugsBunnyBabsBunny   999 Maple Street
```

I've tried using the consolidate feature but you don't get the option for concatenate.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the source Excel file that you have, are all of the duplicate addresses grouped together, or are they spread out through the document?

Comment: They are spread out, but I can sort by address if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** your addresses are exactly identical, and **if** you sort based on the addresses, and **if** this is a one-time process, you can use the following formulas.

Assuming `Name` is column A and `Street_Address` is column B, and that you have labels in row 1:

Column C will hold the following formula (example from C2): `=IF(B2=B1,CONCATENATE(C1,A2),A2)`

Column D will hold the following formula (example from D2): `=IF(B2=B3,"DeleteMe","KeepMe")`

After you've copied the formulas to all rows, copy and then [paste as values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-cell-values-not-formulas-HA010244903.aspx) in the same spot.

Now, just use [filtering](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx) to only see the "DeleteMe" rows, and delete them all.

Comment: That's easy enough!  Hopefully it is a one time thing, only time will tell.  Thanks!